# Using VBA to query a SQL Server table in Excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel, sql-server-express

I'm trying to query a table in Microsoft Excel using VBA. I've written up some code to try and accomplish this task, but I keep getting an error:

> run-time error '1004': Saying it's a General ODBC error.

I'm not sure what I need to do to get this code to run properly so I can query this table.

I'm using SQL Server Express, the server I'm connecting to: `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Database:

[Databaselink](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780735666054-files/9780735666054_files.zip)

Querying the products table
VBA Code:

```
Sub ParameterQueryExample()
'---creates a ListObject-QueryTable on Sheet1 that uses the value in 
'        Cell Z1 as the ProductID Parameter for an SQL Query
'        Once created, the query will refresh upon changes to Z1. 

Dim sSQL As String
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim rDest As Range

'--build connection string-must use ODBC to allow parameters
Const sConnect = "ODBC;" & _
    "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
    "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
    "Database=TSQL2012;" & _
    "Trusted_Connection=yes"

'--build SQL statement
sSQL = "SELECT *" & _
        " FROM TSQL2012.Production.Products Products" & _
        " WHERE Products.productid = ?;"

'--create ListObject and get QueryTable
Set rDest = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
rDest.CurrentRegion.Clear  'optional- delete existing table

Set qt = rDest.Parent.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcExternal, _
    Source:=Array(sConnect), Destination:=rDest).QueryTable

With qt.Parameters.Add("ProductID", xlParamTypeVarChar)
    .SetParam xlRange, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z1")
    .RefreshOnChange = True
End With

'--populate QueryTable
With qt
    .CommandText = sSQL
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True  'add any other table properties here
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .Refresh
End With

Set qt = Nothing
Set rDest = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look here: [http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). There are few ways to connect to sql server and few providers... Try different connection settings.

Comment: On which _line_ does this occur? throw us a clue.

Answer (score 2):

the solution to do this is the next

```
Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _
"OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=SERVER_NAME;Data Source=CONNECTION_ADRESS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False", _
True, xlYes, Range("A2"))

lo.QueryTable.CommandType = xlCmdSql
lo.QueryTable.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME"

With lo.QueryTable.Parameters.Add("Currency code", xlParamTypeVarChar)
    .SetParam xlRange, ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    .RefreshOnChange = True
End With

lo.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

This you can create a listObject from a SQL Query.